# Pulling Bloomberg market data into R: bad date format

Tags: r, date, bloomberg

The default date format for BDH (Bloomberg Excel add-in) is '30/06/2012'. Copied/csv across, this is not picked up as a date in R when using either a dataframe or zoo object. Is there a handy way to turn (this text date) into usable dates?

Comment: You need to use `as.Date("30/06/2012", "%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: Yes, if in doubt, [read the documentation](https://github.com/Rblp/Rblpapi/blob/master/man/bdh.Rd#L17).

Comment: The question refers to BDH Excel. The RBLPapi package is a different source that requires the terminal and I have no access. @DirkEddelbuettel

Comment: Point conceded, but even the Excel function probably has documentation. And I supposed you need a Bloomberg terminal either way to access Bloomberg,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R is not friendly towards the formats used by Bloomberg/Excel. You need to use `as.Date("30/06/2012", "%d/%m/%Y")`.